# не меняется положение полей для ввода текста при использовании GridBagLayout

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Tabbet extends JFrame {
    JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4, panel5, panel6, panel7, panel8, panel9, panel10; //создание панелей 
    JLabel label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7, label8, label9, label10; //создание иконки 
    JTabbedPane tabbed; //панель вкладок 
    JTextField text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7;
    //GridBagConstraints gbc =new GridBagConstraints (); 
    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();


    public Tabbet() {
        super("Health Certificate"); //название окна 
        //размещение 
        setLayout(gbl);





        /*цвета*/


        /*вкладки*/
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel4 = new JPanel();
        panel5 = new JPanel();
        panel6 = new JPanel();
        panel7 = new JPanel();
        panel8 = new JPanel();
        panel9 = new JPanel();
        panel10 = new JPanel();
        /*поле для ввода текста*/
        text1 = new JTextField("id", 20);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(text1, gbc);

        text2 = new JTextField("birthday", 20);
        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        panel1.add(text2, gbc);

        text3 = new JTextField("sex", 20);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        panel1.add(text3, gbc);

        text4 = new JTextField("race", 20);
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        panel1.add(text4, gbc);

        text5 = new JTextField("blood type", 20);
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        panel1.add(text5, gbc);

        text6 = new JTextField("heigh", 20);
        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        /*gbc.gridwidth= 2; 
        gbc.gridheight= 1;*/
        panel1.add(text6, gbc);

        text7 = new JTextField("weight", 20);
        gbc.gridx = 6;
        gbc.gridy = 6;
        panel1.add(text7, gbc);

        /*вкладки*/
        label1 = new JLabel("Tabbet1");
        label2 = new JLabel("Tabbet2");
        label3 = new JLabel("Tabbet3");
        label4 = new JLabel("Tabbet4");
        label5 = new JLabel("Tabbet5");
        label6 = new JLabel("Tabbet6");
        label7 = new JLabel("Tabbet7");
        label8 = new JLabel("Tabbet8");
        label9 = new JLabel("Tabbet9");
        label10 = new JLabel("Tabbet10");

        /*текст на вкладках*/
        panel1.add(label1);
        panel2.add(label2);
        panel3.add(label3);
        panel4.add(label4);
        panel5.add(label5);
        panel6.add(label6);
        panel7.add(label7);
        panel8.add(label8);
        panel9.add(label9);
        panel10.add(label10);

        /*поле для ввода вкладка 1*/
        panel1.add(text1, gbc);








        tabbed = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbed.add("1", panel1);
        tabbed.add("Tabbet2", panel2);
        tabbed.add("Tabbet3", panel3);
        tabbed.add("Tabbet4", panel4);
        tabbed.add("Tabbet5", panel5);
        tabbed.add("Tabbet6", panel6);
        tabbed.add("Tabbet7", panel7);
        tabbed.add("Tabbet8", panel8);
        tabbed.add("Tabbet9", panel9);
        tabbed.add("Tabbet10", panel10);

        tabbed.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(680, 350));
        this.add(tabbed);






        this.setSize(700, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new Tabbet();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GridBagLayout применять надо к JPanel
к примеру:

```
selectPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());
faceaccTextField.setName("faceaccTextField");
faceaccTextField.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(80, 35));
gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
gridBagConstraints.gridy = 3;
gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
selectPanel.add(faceaccTextField, gridBagConstraints);
```

И вообще зачем вручную все это делать, пользуйтесь встроенными конструктарами в среде разработке.

Comment: не особо поняла как именно(

Comment: вручную интереснее)

Comment: В Вашем случае, когда вы создали вкладки(они же JPanel) , то к этой вкладке устанавливаете GridBagLayout : panel1.setLayout(gbl);

Comment: я пробовала, он выдает ошибку, именно по этому не понимаю что тут не так(

Comment: если: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null) , то к Tabbet также надо применять лаяут

Comment: т.е вот так?  tabbed.setLayout(gbl);, если так, то тоже выдает ошибку (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Tabbet.<init>(Tabbet.java:25)
 at Tabbet.main(Tabbet.java:207))

Comment: странно, скопировал Ваш код и подправил, все работает

Comment: вот это действительно странно( тогда я вообще ничего не понимаю

Comment: я пользуюсь intellij IDEA может в этом дело?

Comment: нет, у меня в ней запускается https://imageshost.ru/image/zaT9U

Comment: а в чем тогда может быть дело?

Comment: Скиньте свой код еще раз, посмотрю.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4Nj4wxqF вот тут

Comment: в 25 строке вы применяете лайут к еще не созданной панели, применяйте уже после того как создали панель ниже 36 строки

Comment: Супер!! сработало, спасибо большое!!!хахахха